# After update of either npm, or ng-packagr, publish tries to use incorrect package name and version

Tags: angular, npm, ng-packagr

After migration to Node@16.14.2, NPM@8.5.0 and Angular@13 I am not able to publish package generated by ng-packager to npm repository.

package.json:

```
{
"name": "@me/ng13",
"version": "1.0.0",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
"test": "ng test",
"packagr": "ng-packagr -p ng-package.json",
"publish": "npm publish dist"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~13.3.0",
"@angular/common": "~13.3.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~13.3.0",
"@angular/core": "~13.3.0",
"@angular/forms": "~13.3.0",
"@angular/localize": "~13.3.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.0",
"@angular/router": "~13.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^8.0.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^3.0.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^7.1.2",
"@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^4.0.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^5.0.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip": "^4.0.1",
"@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.0.2",
"@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^5.0.0",
"rxjs": "~7.5.0",
"tslib": "^2.3.0",
"zone.js": "~0.11.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.7",
"@angular/cli": "~13.3.7",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.3.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
"@types/node": "^12.11.1",
"jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
"karma": "~6.3.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
"karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
"typescript": "~4.6.2",
"ng-packagr": "^13.3.1"
},
"description": "This project was generated with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) version 13.3.7.",
"author": "me",
"license": "MIT"
}
```

After ng-packagr -p ng-package.json I can see correct package.json with expected version, but after npm publish dist there is some weird information about the package:

npm run publish

```
> @me/ng13@1.0.0 publish
> npm publish dist

npm notice
npm notice package: dist@0.1.2
npm notice === Tarball Contents ===
npm notice 13B   .npmignore
npm notice 200B  HISTORY.md
npm notice 7B    README.md
npm notice 1.4kB bin/dist.js
npm notice 1.8kB lib/dist.js
npm notice 602B  package.json
npm notice 4.5kB test/dist.test.js
npm notice 89B   test/fixtures/copyright.js
npm notice 199B  test/fixtures/input.js
npm notice 289B  test/fixtures/out/input.copyright.js
npm notice 229B  test/fixtures/out/input.copyright.min.js
npm notice 199B  test/fixtures/out/input.js
npm notice 139B  test/fixtures/out/input.min.js
npm notice 20B   test/mocha.opts
npm notice === Tarball Details ===
npm notice name:          dist
npm notice version:       0.1.2
npm notice filename:      dist-0.1.2.tgz
npm notice package size:  2.7 kB
npm notice unpacked size: 9.7 kB
npm notice shasum:        8898629cc251297e36d1354a9a9598619aba5b1a
npm notice integrity:     sha512-TmsZfJybRs3IZ[...]frqZyuqkz/sOQ==
npm notice total files:   14
```

So I am wondering why name and version in publish step are incorrect and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

So after all these upgrades instead of `npm publish dist` I should use `npm publish ./dist`

Comment: saved my day - FYI - I was getting the exact same incorrect version number for the dist - also I had done the same node updates with angular 16